# How to set identical table widths in Birt?

Tags: width, birt

We have like 30 tables in our report each with 5 columns and identical, now our chief wants the first column to be wider, it is possible to drag the bars with mouse and widen the column, but in order to do that one has to play with the other columns as well in the end table A column 5 is 109 pixels, Table B column 5 is 110 pixels, Table C column 5 is 109 pixels and Table D column 5 is 111 pixels for example... It is very difficult to adjust the widths with hand... Is there a better, smarter / faster way? In the end all tables should be with the same width/length.

Answer (score 3):

Select the table in the outline.  Select one column or several columns.

Property Editor > General define the widith for the selected columns.

Ensure your masterpage is properly formatted to fit the widith of your columns

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I know where to input table width, but the funny thing is although I write a value there, the width of the table doesnt change... and remains the same. For example a table below has the same width length with table above, but still a column is shorter than the table above...

Comment: @Anarkie Columns without defined widths automatically split the available area.  Tables by default fit the max width allowed by the master page.  If you select all the columns and change their width the table will adjust to fit, but the master page may need to be adjusted.

Comment: Like I said the columns have a defined width but still the table doesnt adapt, on the other hand selecting all columns and giving a width will give all selected columns the same width but on my tables, column widths are different, i.e. 100 points, 85 points...